# Find max string value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table with a column that is used to indicate a position. Positions start with A and could go up to AZ, just like in Excel.
E.G.

```
Row | Position
----|---------
 1  |    A
 1  |    B
 1  |    C
 :  |    :
 1  |    Z
 1  |   AA
 1  |   AB
 2  |    A
 2  |    B
```

etc.

If I use `select max(position) from table where row = 1` the result is always Z and not AB.

How would I select the maximum value of the column which is varchar type?

Comment: What position is `':'` meant to be?

Comment: Did not want to type all values between A to Z so it indicates the values between C and Z :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this with `MAX()` then you can convert the values to right-aligned values:

```
select max(right('  ' + position, 2))
from t
where row = 1;
```

(This assumes that the maximum length is 2, based on the reference to Excel.)

You can remove any leading spaces using `ltrim()`:

```
select ltrim(max(right('  ' + position, 2)))
from t
where row = 1;
```

The advantage of this approach is that it fits easily into `GROUP BY`:

```
select row, ltrim(max(right('  ' + position, 2))) as position
from t
group by row;
```

Comment: @der_roedie is there a reason that you accepted this answer which uses the same code as my answer but was posted later?

Comment: No not really but I was not able to accept both answers and therefor I choose Gordon's reply because he explained a little bit more in detail.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to do it:

```
select top 1 position from mytable where row = 1 order by len(position) desc, position desc
```

This works by sorting records by descending position length, and then by descending position, and then selecting the top record in the resultset.

---

If you want the per-`row` maximum, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select row, position
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by row order by len(position) desc, position desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Tested this approach vs the right(....) approach with a table with 10M rows. This is about 10 - 15% faster.

Answer (score 3):

Left pad the value of `position` with spaces (if needed), so they are all comparable and then get the max:

```
select ltrim(max(right('  ' + position, 2))) 
from tablename
where row = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6cbd8f6d43e3a7235084c27a9f8377f1).
Result (for your sample data):
`AB`